# Nestjs Casl - check if user in ManyToMany relationship with resource

Tags: javascript, typescript, express, nestjs, casl

I'm trying to make an access control system based on many to many relationships between Users and Resources (projects, documents and others). The main key is that everywhere I see role based AC which allow users to edit a type of resource not specific resources based on IDs.
What i have:
Project: {id, ..., editors: [ User: { id, ...}, User: {id...} ]
I want to check using casl (I'm open to other solutions than casl) if the User from the request is in the Project.editors array.

In AbilityFactory defineAbility(userId)

```
export enum Action {
    Edit = 'Edit',
    View = 'View',
}

export enum Resource {
    Project = 'project',
}
const user = await this.userService.findOne(userId);

can(Action.Edit, Project, { editors: user });
```

In controller (temp solution, I will use guard in future) I check it this way:

```
const ability = await this.abilityFactory.defineAbility(userId);
const project = await this.projectService.findOne(id);

if (!ability.can(Action.Edit, project)) {
    throw new ForbiddenException('Access denied!');
}
```

But this doesn't work well, always returning false...

Any solution?

Comment: Now, I'm trying implement this: interface with editors, viewers fields, implement this interface in each entity I want. Then in casl iterate over each interface field in incoming resource given in function defineAbility as second arguments. I think about move this arrays to the user side, then I can check all permissions for user in incoming requests.

Answer (score 0):

Underneath the hood CASL is using the MongoDB Query Language as defined here:
https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/query-documents/

For searching for a field within a list of complex type (as constructed by ORM 1:n or n:m relationships) you can use the $elemMatch operator which yields a positive result if any document within an array matches on a certain attribute:

```
can(Action.Edit, Project, { editors: {
                                $elemMatch: {
                                    userId: user.userId
                                }
                        });
```